# Flutter - Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, mobile

When I run a flutter project I get an error:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @221d66ef

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

How can I solve this problem?

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yuaS.png)

[Flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLFPH.png)

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feCEH.png)

Comment: For such questions to get faster answers, please always share details like, Host OS, Android Studio, SDK, Build Tools, Gradle and JDK versions; in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a network error because building the Gradle task requires an internet connection; otherwise, the Gradle assemble task will not work and will terminate. If you encounter a Java-related error, try running your project in Android Studio. This will download the necessary Java versions and other dependencies. Additionally, Gradle tasks will build faster in Android Studio.

I have saw your flutter doctor report.Your Installation is incomplete.
Go to Android Studio-> manager->Android Sdk->Sdk tools tab -> install Android commandline tool chain press ok then

[image: YouTube Video]

Comment: I tried VPN and Android Studio, got the same result. |
[Android studio run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxrhs.png)

Comment: I did this, but the problem remained. Thanks for the answer. | [Flutter doctor update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLFPH.png) | [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbIz2.png)